# Agregar elementos a una cola por consola en PHP

Tags: php, html, queue

Básicamente estudiando haciendo un código en base una cola, consta en un programa básico en el que los datos ingresados por la pagina web, deben agregarse a la cola de datos , que es por decirlo así, unos pedidos registrados, entonces la idea es que se sigan registrando pedidos, y que cada vez que se agregue uno nuevo se añada en la siguiente posición de la cola. Sin embargo no encuentro la forma de lograr que se mantenga cada vez que se presione el botón de enviar.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Listado de pedidos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <b>
            <i>
                <u>
                    <br><br><h1>Listado de pedidos</h1>
                </u>
            </i>
        </b>
        Ingrese los nuevos pedidos solicitados por los clientes.
    </center>
    <form action="mostrar.php" method="post" target="ventana">
        <center>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br/>
            <input type="text" name="cedula"><br><br/>
            <input type="text" name="producto"><br><br/>
            <input type="number" name="cantidad"><br><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar">
            <br/><br/>
            <iframe name="ventana" src="mostrar.php" width="500"5height="1000" frameborder="1" scrolling="si"></iframe>
        </center>
    </form>


    
<?php
    include("mostrar.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la otra partes

```
<?php

$DatoNombre = new SplQueue();
    $DatoNombre->enqueue("Marcus");
    $DatoNombre->enqueue("Anthony");
    $DatoNombre->enqueue("Fatima");
    
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    
    $DatoNombre->enqueue($_POST['nombre']);

    echo $DatoNombre->count();

    $DatoNombre->rewind();

    while($DatoNombre->valid())
    {
        echo $DatoNombre->current(), PHP_EOL;
        echo "<br/>";
        $DatoNombre->next();
        echo "<br/>";
    }

}

?>
```